# Friendly URL's on HTTPS (500 Internal error)

Tags: .htaccess, https, friendly-url, internal

After enabling https on all site I'm getting (500 Internal Server Error ) when I browse anything with friendly url,

But the links without friendly url are Ok,

Here is my htaccess file:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options -MultiViews
#Options All -Indexes

# This can be uncommented to compress js and css files
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# This can be uncommented to set cache control for image, js, and css files
#Header unset ETag
#FileETag None
#<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|swf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
#Header unset Last-Modified
#Header set Expires "Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
#Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
#</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|tpl)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.uae-shipping.net/$1 [R,L]
#Handle all category links.  Static category text followed by ID, followed by path
#The "category" text here needs to be changed if the language variable category is changed
RewriteRule ^category\/(.+/)location/(.+)$ browse_categories.php?id=$1&location=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category\/(.+)$ browse_categories.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

#Handle all location links.  Static location text followed by ID, followed by path
#The "location" text here needs to be changed if the language variable location is changed
RewriteRule ^location\/(.+)$ browse_locations.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

#Rewrite pages
RewriteRule ^pages\/(.+)\.html$ page.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

#Rewrite Blog
RewriteRule ^blog.html$ blog.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog\/([^/]+)-([0-9]+).html$ blog_post.php?id=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^blog\/category\/(.+)-([0-9]+).html$ blog.php?category_id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

#Rewrite listing/banner website out
RewriteRule ^out-([0-9]+)\.html$ out.php?listing_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^out-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ out.php?listing_id=$1&banner_id=$2 [L]

#Rewrite listings
#Ignore any physical files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ listing.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/images\.html$ listing_images.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/send-message\.html$ listing_email.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/send-message-friend\.html$ listing_email_friend.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/reviews\.html$ listing_reviews.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/add-review\.html$ listing_reviews_add.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/classifieds\.html$ listing_classifieds.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/documents\.html$ listing_documents.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/events\.html$ listing_events.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/suggestion\.html$ listing_suggestion.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/claim\.html$ listing_claim.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

#Rewrite classifieds
RewriteRule ^classified/[^/]+-([0-9]+)\.html$ classified.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^classified/[^/]+-([0-9]+)/images\.html$ classified_images.php?classified_id=$1 [L,NC]

#Rewrite events
RewriteRule ^event/[^/]+-([0-9]+)\.html$ event.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

#Rewrite sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ xml.php?type=sitemap [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please review this discussion http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261726/are-questions-about-webserver-config-files-and-rewrite-rules-on-topic to find better place for your question

Comment: First step is to look into the server log and see what error is reported.